# Trying to query within query but it doesn't work

Tags: c#, sql, foreach, parameter-passing

I am trying to populate a table with data from SQL and i have to query in query in order to get the expected results.

Here is how i am trying to do:

```
// Queries
var transakcionet = db.Query("SELECT * FROM Ditari WHERE IDUrdheresa = @0", ID);

// IDKlientit has unique value so the below query will always return one row
var klienti = "SELECT cEmertimi_i_klientit FROM Klienti WHERE (IDKlientit = @0)";


<tbody>

@foreach(var transakcioni in transakcionet){
   <tr>
      // This works
      @foreach(var kontoja in db.Query(kontoTrans, transakcioni.IDKontos)){
         <td>@kontoja.cNumri_i_kontos</td>
      }
      // This is what is causing the error (i guess)
      @foreach(var klja in db.Query(klienti, transakcioni.IDKlientit)){
         <td>@klja.cEmertimi_i_klientit</td>
      }
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

I dont know what i am missing but.

Here is the error message:

> No value given for one or more required parameters.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: No value given for one or more required parameters.

Comment: Can you show implementation of `db.Query`?

Comment: db = Database.Open("nameofdb");

Comment: is the property `transakcioni.IDKlientit` always `!= null`?

Comment: Yes it is a key for this table ...

Answer (score 1):

@webber2k6 is right. There is something null given to the `Query`.

First, ensure it will not crash (you may need `@using System.Linq` on top of your file):

```
@foreach(var transakcioni in transakcionet.Where(t => t.IDKontos != null && t.IDKlientit != null){
<tr>
    // This works
    @foreach(var kontoja in db.Query(kontoTrans, transakcioni.IDKontos)){
        <td>@kontoja.cNumri_i_kontos</td>
    }
    // This is what is causing the error (i guess)
    @foreach(var klja in db.Query(klienti, transakcioni.IDKlientit)){
        <td>@klja.cEmertimi_i_klientit</td>
    }
</tr>
```

But this will not explain why the value is `null` in the first place. Obviously, this makes sense only if those `ID*` properties are nullable, which, I guess, is the case regarding the error message you get.

Answer (score 0):

your code fixes didn`t work but your suggestion did!

I handled "when its null" and now it works how i want

This is what i did:

```
@foreach(var transakcioni in transakcionet){
  <tr>
     @foreach(var kontoja in db.Query(kontoTrans, transakcioni.IDKontos)){
             <td>@kontoja.cNumri_i_kontos</td>
         }
    @if(transakcioni.IDKlientit == null){
        <td>No name</td>
    }else {
            foreach(var kli in db.Query(klienti, transakcioni.IDKlientit)){
            <td>@kli.cEmertimi_i_klientit</td>
        }}
```

Comment: What did not work? Linq seems more elegant that `null`checking inside the foreach loop.